# Firebase - app unresponsive for a long time (because of data syncing?)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a RunKeeper-like app.

This issue happens when the app has captured lots of location data, and all the data were saved locally because of no internet connection.

When I connect to the wifi after a long time and open the app, it displays the processing icon for a long time.

```
    showProcessingIcon()

    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        //.... process and display data....

        hideProcessingIcon()    
    }) { (error) in
        //.... handle error....

        hideProcessingIcon()            
    }
```

Sometimes the processing icon goes away after a min or so. Sometimes I had to quit the app after waiting for 5mins or so, with the processing icon still spinning. Sometimes I noticed the app was offloaded while I was waiting for the processing to finish (phone auto-locks after 1min).

Any idea how to avoid this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really prevent the synchronization of data while the Firebase SDK is online.  If you have a large pending write, it will take as long as it needs to take to finish, and it will block other writes until it's finished.

What you can do instead is collect data into some other store (a local file or database) instead of writing directly to the database with the SDK.  Then, you can choose when that data finally gets written to Realtime Database (but it will still take just as long to complete).

Comment: "it will block other writes until it's finished" Will it block read operations as well? That's what I am trying to do in my case - reading back the data, no writes.

Comment: All requests are pipelined over a single websocket.  If that websocket is busy with some read/write, then all the others will have to wait for it to complete.